# Condition Check fails in run() of a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement

```
public class MultiThreadExample extends Thread {
    public static int count=0;
    static String s="";
    synchronized public static String read(){
        String line="";
        System.out.println("Enter new line:");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            line=br.readLine();
            count++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return line;

    }

    synchronized public static void write(String line){
        try {
            BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://name.txt"));
            br.write(line);
            System.out.println(line);
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void run(){
        if(count==0){
            System.out.println("Read " + s + " Count " + count);
            s=read();
            System.out.println("Read " + s + " Count " + count);
        }
        else{
            write(s);
            System.out.println("Write" + s + " Count " + count);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MultiThreadExample th1=new MultiThreadExample();
        MultiThreadExample th2=new MultiThreadExample();
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
    }

}
```

The count check in run() method is not working. Any idea why? The count increases with each call, I can see, but the check is not working, and each time the control passes to read() method, and does not go to write()

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there any other efficient way to call multiple methods from a two threads, depending on situation?

P.S. I am trying to read input using one thread, and write the input value to a file in another thread

Comment: try to declare count like this: public volatile static int count=0;

Comment: nope, its still not working.. :(

Comment: @Win.ubuntu - That's not necessary at all. *synchronized* blocks/methods ensure a *happens-before* exists. Even if you add `volatile`, the JIT will most probably just *remove / ignore* it for you.

Comment: since your condition (i.e count read ) is not thread safe, the  threads can do if (count==0) ,read same value 0 and then wait on blocking readline call. If  your intentions is to let one thread read and other write, then you need a signalling mechanism, like Object.wait and notify. ..... Or you need to be really really fast enough to provide input to the first thread, before the second one checks the condition. :)

Comment: Hi, @Shail016, can you post the answer which you just gave and deleted? Would like to view what you did there. :)

Comment: ok, I have done it. It just locks the check portion only, so that its count is checked by second thread only after its updated by 1st. Yes concurrency is affected here also, and might be good for only 2 threads scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    MultiThreadExample th1=new MultiThreadExample();
    MultiThreadExample th2=new MultiThreadExample();
    th1.start();
   try {
    th1.join();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
    th2.start();
```

Comment: Still not working.. same result, only there is a delay because of the sleep()

Comment: Okay, can you please explain to me, why my previous code was not working, and the check failed?

Comment: @Shubharthi Dasgupta here two threads run sequentially, i.e th2.run executes after th1.run finishes

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new `BufferedReader` for every line. Use the same one for the life of the socket. You're losing data read-ahead by each `BufferedReader`.

Comment: ok, but that is a different issue, the if(count==0) condition check fails. Any idea why? once that is solved, I will change the BufferedReader line

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the static except main method ... All you need to ensure is that read and write don't change/read "count" at the same time ... Use a different lock object like "lockObject" and use wait() and notify(). You are looking for a producer/consumer sort of a pattern here. Here is an example: http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/

Answer (score 1):

can also try 'similar' approach. , which ever thread enters first reads, and the later one waits for the former to read and then it writes. (it doesn't need your static methods to be synchronized)

```
static ReentrantLock l = new ReentrantLock();
        public void run(){
            l.lock();
            if(count==0){
                System.out.println("Read " + s + " Count " + count);
             s=read();
            l.unlock();              
            System.out.println("Read " + s + " Count " + count);
            }
            else{
                write(s);
                System.out.println("Write" + s + " Count " + count);
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Okay, can you please explain to me, why my previous code was not working, and the check failed?

@Shail016 explained it in a comment on your question.  Here's one possible sequence of events.

main thread calls `th1.start()`, calls `th2.start()`, and then exits.

thread 1 enters the `run()` method, sees that count==0, enters the `read()` method, calls `System.out.println(...)`

thread 2 enters the `run()` method, sees that count==0, tries to enter the `read()` method, gets blocked, waiting for the mutex.

thread 1 returns from the `System.out.println(...)` call, reads a line, increments `count`, and returns,

thread 2 is allowed in to `read()`, etc., etc.,

etc.

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mark `count` as volatile. This ensures that changes from one thread are seen by other threads. As long as only one thread updates `count`, this is OK, otherwise, you could use either an `AtomicInteger`, an `AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater` in conjunction with a volatile field or (if you measure high contention, which is unlikely in your case) a `LongAdder` (all classes are from the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package, the last is only available in Java 8).

Comment: *Mark count as volatile.*. Not nececessary. *synchronization* ensures a *happens before*.

Comment: Also, not sufficient.  The problem is that access to `count` is unsynchronized  A thread that assumes the "reader" role will perform several I/O operations before it increments count.  That gives the other thread plenty of opportunity to _test_ count (access to count is not synchronized at the point where it is tested) before the increment happens.  Thus, both threads are quite likely to assume the "reader" role.